# Adding constraints Gurobi Python

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

```
city=["A","B"]
week=[0,1,2,3]
S={"A":[5,15,25,35], "B":[80,11,31,30]}

model=gp.Model()
I = model.addVars(city, week, name="I")

model.setObjective(...)

# try 1:
model.addConstrs(S[c][w] <= I[c][w] for c in city for w in week)

# try 2:
for c in city:
    for w in week:
        model.addConstr(S[c][w] <= I[c][w])
```

Hello, I am trying to solve a problem and I need to add a constraint for each city and for each week. However, I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for the for loop when trying to add the constraint. Could you help me I am not sure how to correctly add them?

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`model.addVars()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addvars.html#pythonmethod:Model.addVars) returns a gurobi tupledict where each key is stored as tuplelist:

```py
>>> print(I)
In [64]: I
Out[64]:
{('A', 0): <gurobi.Var I[A,0]>,
 ('A', 1): <gurobi.Var I[A,1]>,
 ('A', 2): <gurobi.Var I[A,2]>,
 ('A', 3): <gurobi.Var I[A,3]>,
 ('B', 0): <gurobi.Var I[B,0]>,
 ('B', 1): <gurobi.Var I[B,1]>,
 ('B', 2): <gurobi.Var I[B,2]>,
 ('B', 3): <gurobi.Var I[B,3]>}
```

Hence, the expression `I[c][w]` yields a KeyError. Use `I[c,w]` or `I[(c, w)]` instead.

That said, your 'constraints' are just lower bounds for the variables; thus, there's no real need for constraints. You can just set the lower bounds for the variables:

```
for c in city:
    for w in week:
        I[c, w].lb = S[c][w]
```